# Are there any Hindu stories involving non-artificial weather?

Tags: scripture, indra, nature

I find the characters in Hinduism rarely discuss the weather, which I find odd.

Comment: Intellectual Hinduism gives souls to Weather Elements

Comment: 'non-artificial weather' - you mean natural weather? Check [this](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga28/kishkindha_28_frame.htm) link.

Comment: Kishkindha kand of Ramcharitmanas also describe natural weather (rainy seasons), are you looking something like mentioned imyhe link provided by sv.?..

Comment: Ritusamharam poem of Kalidasa is all about weather. It discusses the 6 seasons in great detail.